How to connect points belonging to the same ship in ElasticSearch
I have an API which has ship data and I'm extracting the data using Python for 1 hour. The data I extract is in form given below
[{'Timestamp': '2024-04-30T22:06:27.124502+00:00',
  'ShipId': 367162320,
  'Location': {'long': -87.62471833333333, 'lat': 41.889201666666665},
  'SpeedOverGround': 0,
  'ShipName': 'WENDELLA'},               
 {'Timestamp': '2024-04-30T22:07:14.240821+00:00',
  'ShipId': 367199310,
  'Location': {'long': -118.19945833333333, 'lat': 33.763063333333335},
  'SpeedOverGround': 0,
  'ShipName': 'CATALINA JET        '},       
 {'Timestamp': '2024-04-30T22:07:27.191644+00:00',
  'ShipId': 367162320,
  'Location': {'long': -87.624715, 'lat': 41.88918666666667},
  'SpeedOverGround': 0,
  'ShipName': 'WENDELLA'}]

I am using ElasticSearch client to send the data giving a new mapping for Location as geo_point and using a primary_key for each record to have a unique identifier, I send the index to elasticsearch through which I can create data views and also plot them on a map. Now, the thing is I want the points to connect with respect to timestamp for each ship to know the 1 hour trajectory of the ship. I cannot for my life get the points to connect. The reference Geo-line aggregation apparently shows how to get the points to connect with a line. I tried using the mapping in the PUT test given but to no avail. Any Help?
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "my_location": { "type": "geo_point" },
            "group":       { "type": "keyword" },
            "@timestamp":  { "type": "date" }
        }
    }
}

